# how to make smoothe transition between refreshes

Tags: php, html, jquery

Made slideshow from folder containig images with size from 4,5MB to 12 MB using something like code bellow
then page reloads image can't load fast, and transition not smooth.
How can i achive smooth image change? Is it possible preload next page somehow?
Or is it possible to change php to make smooth image changes?

[UPD]
Also should mention earlier image folder is big more then 5+GB. And it will run on RPi with only 2GB of RAM. And i need to account that content of folder could be changed.

````
<!doctypehtml>
<html class="no-js"lang="en">
<head><meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="15"http-equiv="refresh">
    <meta content="no-cache"http-equiv="cache-control">
    <style>
        *{margin:0;padding:0}
        body{background-color:#000}
        div{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden}
        img{position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%)}
        .bg{width:105vw;filter:blur(8px) saturate(80%)}
        .fr{max-width:100vw;max-height:100vh}
        @keyframes 
        fa{0%{opacity:0}
            20%{opacity:1}
            86%{opacity:1}
            100%{opacity:0}
        }
        .a-f{animation:fa 15s infinite}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div>
            <?php
$Id = "../mm/";
$im = glob($Id . "*.{jpg,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE);
$rI = $im[array_rand($im)];
echo '<img class="bg a-f" src="' .    $rI .    '" alt=""/><img class="fr a-f" src="' .    $rI .    '" alt=""/>';?>
        </div>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: If you refresh the page (as per your `<meta content="15"http-equiv="refresh">` code), then obviously it won't be smooth because it reloads the entire page from the server. Instead, use some kind of JS image gallery / slideshow plugin to display all your images nicely. There are dozens of them you can easily search for online, just find one which suits your needs.  PHP is not the issue here...PHP's job is only to return a list of the available image files. It does not control what the browser is doing.

Comment: if use code that load all images in folder, it consume all the memory, my folder with images unfortunately not small 5+GB

Comment: Well the browser does not need to load all the images immediately, it can load the one which is currently being displayed, then remove that from the DOM and load the next one from the server. (All that needs to be preloaded is a list of image URLs for it to choose from.) Choose carefully which plugin you use, so that it uses this technique (instead of, for example, having all images pre-loaded in img tags, and just showing and hiding them). Either you do that, or you restrict the number of images which the script can load at once, or you stay with your current design.

Comment: `it will run on RPi with only 2GB of RAM`...what will? The PHP code? Or the browser which is showing the web page? Or both??

Comment: browser in kiosk mode